# What is a Resolvent?

Tags: polynomials, soft-question

I've heard that a resolvent is very useful in finding the roots of the polynomial. But I'm not sure what a resolvent even is. As much as I can figure out, it's just another polynomial. But that makes no sense, because why would you want extra work?

And how would you find the resolvent of a polynomial? For example, what's the resolvent of a quintic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic

Comment: .. I'm still confused.

Comment: I am too.  Trying to work it out for the both of us XD

Comment: @SimpleArt xD Wikipedia just says the resolvent of a depressed quartic... so is it possible or not to have the resolvent of a quintic, a quadratic, a cubic, etc.?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_(Galois_theory) Oh no, you can have those.

Comment: I haven't really gotten too far in Abstract Algebra. I really only know very little about the basics...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45853/discussion-between-simple-art-and-crescendo).

Comment: I know the meaning that says a resolvent is in particular the equation in one variable resulting after eliminating the other ones in a system of equations.

Comment: @Piquito Too many systems of equations IMO

Comment: @Simple Art: I have read books in which after eliminating a variable in a system of two quadratic equations called the final equation "resolvente" (in Spanish". And we know that this equation is in general of the fourth degree. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resolvent of a polynomial is a polynomial of lower degree who's roots relate to the roots of the original polynomial.  Anyways, let us find the solution to the general quartic, and I will highlight the resolvent cubic.

Solve for $x$ in

$$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$$

$$x^4+b'x^3+c'x^2+d'x+e'=0\tag{divide both sides by $a$}$$

$$u^4+a_uu^2+b_uu+c_u=0\tag{Substitution $x=u-\frac{b'}4$}$$

$$u^4+nu^2+n'=mu^2+m'u+m''\tag{introduce new constants}$$

By equating parts:

$$\begin{cases}n-m=a_u\\m'=-b_u\\n'-m''=c_u\end{cases}$$

Since we want both sides to be perfect squares,

$$(u^2+\lambda_1)^2=(\sqrt mu+\lambda_2)^2$$

So that we may take the square root of both sides and take the remaining quadratic.  But to do that, we must first know what $\lambda_{1,2}$ are.

To do this, expand both sides, then equate more parts.

$$u^4+2\lambda_1u^2+\lambda_1^2=mu^2+2\sqrt m\lambda_2u+\lambda_2^2$$

This gives us a whole new set of things to equate:

$$\begin{cases}2\lambda_1=n\\\lambda_1^2=n'\\2\sqrt m\lambda_2=m'\\\lambda_2^2=m''\end{cases}$$

Interestingly, if you solve by repeatedly substituting with everything we know, the solutions to $\lambda_{1,2}$ are easy, if we knew what $n$ and $m$ were.

Solving for $n,n',m,m',$ and $m''$ involve a cubic polynomial:

> $$\boxed{(m'')^3-(4a_u^3-c_u)(m'')^2+2a_ub_u^2m''-\frac14b_u^4=0}$$

The above is a resolvent cubic that has a root equal to $m''$ with coefficients in known constants $a,b,c$.

You may derive other constants and then solve the quadratic, and follow up with lots of un-substitutions to get the final answer.

Comment: The longest part was deciding which constant had the best form as a cubic.  T_T many substitutions

Comment: From substituting $x-\frac {u}{4}$ to the next equation, how did you get from $u^4+a_uu^2+b_uu+c_u=0$ to $u^4+nu^2+n'=mu^2+m'u+m''$? What does $n$ and $m$ represent?

Comment: @Crescendo I basically subtracted both sides by $mu^2+m'u+m''$ on both sides, but I called the left side coefficients $n$ instead of $a_u-m$, etc.

Comment: @Crescendo For the cubic of $m''$, I started with $m''=\lambda_2^2$ and snaked my way through with many substitutions.  Then remove square root by moving all things to the other side and squaring, and multiply the final form by $(m'')^2$ on both sides.