# Trouble factoring polynomial expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have been presented with the following question:

> Factorise $$a^2-4b^2\;.$$

I know that the answer is $(a-2b)(a+2b)$, but I have no idea how to get there. Could anybody please help me with this?

Comment: @Ed_4434 Think you can remove the comment now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, I have to ask you what the true meaning behind 'factoring' is.  To me, it is as follows...

> To factor is to derive values for which a polynomial expression is equal to $0$.

So, what we want to do is to set the expression equal to $0$, then solve for $a$ (or $b$).

$$a^2-4b^2=0$$

$$a^2=4b^2$$

$$a=\pm\sqrt{4b^2}=\begin{cases}r_1=\ \ \ 2b\\r_2=-2b\end{cases}$$

Putting this into factored polynomial form:

$$a^2-4b^2=(a-r_1)(a-r_2)=(a-2b)(a+2b)$$

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to *knowing how to get there*. Just notice that 
$$\begin{align}(a-2b)(a+2b) &= a^2 -2ab +2ab -4b^2 \\&= a^2 -4b^2\end{align}$$

In general, the expression you are given is a **difference of squares** because $$a^2 -4b^2 = a^2 - (2b)^2\;.$$ Any time you have a difference of squares, you can factor it:
$$
x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)\;.
$$

Comment: I think the OP wants to start with $a^2-4b^2$ and work backwards to derive $(a-2b)(a+2b)$

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes this is true, I am needing to see how to get from the question to the answer in a way that is memorable and relatable

Comment: But to factor it, you really do just have to notice it's a difference of squares. And in general there is no procedural way to factor a polynomial expression; you just have to *guess and check*. And since I saw it was a difference of squares, I was able to make a good first guess. :)

Comment: @MikePierce Nah, don't say that mate.  You gotta believe in that real MVP algebra that [solves quartic polynomials](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939889/what-is-a-resolvent/1939954#1939954) using [trigonometric functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940720/trigonometric-quadratic-formula-and-other-trig-solutions-for-roots-of-polynomia).  :D

Comment: I see now that I must simply remember the layout for future questions, and realise it is allowed to change the base accordingly.

Comment: @FlewittConnor That is definitely the recommended path. $x^2-y^2$ is one of those important simple factors you just have to remember.  Also, there's the quadratic formula if you want to get silly :D